# Extruded 'cubes' are frustum culled, my own shapes are not. Any idea why? [Three.js]

Tags: three.js

I'm slowly narrowing down my performance issues and have hit a snag with frustum culling, particularly with my custom, extruded buildings.

I've been doing some testing and it seems that both standard cubes (`CubeGeometry`) and my own custom extruded cubes get culled as soon as they leave the screen bounds. This can be seen by monitoring the number of calls, faces, and vertices being rendered.

If I then try to render a building shape, using the same technique as the extruded cubes, I am no longer able to get it to cull at the screen bounds – something is keeping it rendering until far beyond the edge of the screen.

Here is a jsFiddle of the issue in which you can see the building example which doesn't cull. You can uncomment the `initCubes()` call to see how the cubes work fine. Controls are mouse-wheel to zoom and click to pan: http://jsfiddle.net/tuJAB/

I've been pulling my hair out with this for days so I'd appreciate any and all help.

Thanks!

**Update**

After more testing it seems that it might be something to do with the coordinates I'm using to create the vertices. If I create the vertices relative to the origin (0,0) and then move the entire mesh using `position` then culling works. If I create the vertices at the right position (around 5000 units from (0,0)) and don't change `position` then culling doesn't work as expected.

Still haven't nailed this yet so the help is needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I create the vertices relative to the origin (0,0) and then move the entire mesh using `position` then culling works.

That.

Comment: Confirmed. I'm now offsetting my vertices so they are relative to (0,0) and then using that same offset to place the mesh `position` back where it should be. Culling works perfectly now.

Thanks!

Comment: Although this works with individual meshes, I get the same problem again when those individual, correctly-positioned meshes are merged into a larger single geometry as that merged geometry now has a 0,0 origin. Is there a way to have the merged geometry origin sit in the center point of the individual components, or at least get offset to the correct position?